# return to start of "cin" if user reaches else (C++)

Tags: c++

Trying to make it so if the user doesn't type the right option, it makes the user re-type a new input until they match one of the if statements.

I'm sure its probably a simple thing I just haven't been able to find a way to do it online yet.. If you have some advise or even just links that'd be much appreciated.. Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
cout << "Choose a base from the following options" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << baseChoice1 << endl;
cout << baseChoice2 << endl;
cout << baseChoice3 << endl;
cout << baseChoice4 << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Choice: ";

getline(cin,baseChoice);

transform(baseChoice.begin(), baseChoice.end(), baseChoice.begin(), ::toupper);    
transform(baseChoice1.begin(), baseChoice1.end(), baseChoice1.begin(), ::toupper);
transform(baseChoice2.begin(), baseChoice2.end(), baseChoice2.begin(), ::toupper);
transform(baseChoice3.begin(), baseChoice3.end(), baseChoice3.begin(), ::toupper);
transform(baseChoice4.begin(), baseChoice4.end(), baseChoice4.begin(), ::toupper);

cout << endl;
cout << endl;

        while ((baseChoice != baseChoice1) || (baseChoice != baseChoice2) || (baseChoice != baseChoice3) || (baseChoice != baseChoice4)) 
        {
        cout << "This is not a base option, try again!!" << endl;
        cout << "Choice: ";
        getline(cin,baseChoice);
        }


        if (baseChoice == baseChoice1) {
                baseChoice == baseChoice1;
                cout << "Base: " << baseChoice << endl;
        }
        else if (baseChoice == baseChoice2) {
                baseChoice == baseChoice2;
                cout << "Base: " << baseChoice << endl;
        }
        else if (baseChoice == baseChoice3) {
                baseChoice == baseChoice3;
                cout << "Base: " << baseChoice << endl;
        }
        else if (baseChoice == baseChoice4) {
                baseChoice == baseChoice4;
                cout << "Base: " << baseChoice << endl;
        }
```

EDIT: Added some missing code

EDIT2: Added a while statement

Comment: You can try using "while" loop.

Comment: can you give me an example using a while loop in this situation?

Comment: Original post has been updated with a while statement. No matter what I input, it keeps asking me to put a new input (even if the while term is false)

Comment: There are tons of examples on StackOverflow showing how to handle bad user input. I'm tempted to vote to close this question for lack of research. But, to answer your question, your loop doesn't work because it needs to use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need most of those parentheses in the `while` statement. `while ((baseChoice != baseChoice1) || (baseChoice != baseChoice2))` means exactly the same thing as `while (baseChoice != baseChoice1 || baseChoice != baseChoice2)`.

Comment: @Remy I did try research, but I didn't search it as "bad user input" I guess that might have helped me out in my research process. I was looking up resetting if when user reaches else and couldn't find anything. Thank you for answering my question though, I will try this once I get home, appreciate it.

Comment: @PeteBecker the extra parenthesis may not be technically needed by the compiler, due to operator precendence, but they do provided added readability and reduce the chances of operator precedence being misinterpreted if the conditions being checked are ever changed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau — ((most people) (find (redundant parentheses) distracting)). Or if you prefer a code example, `(x = ((3 * 4) + (5 * 6)))`. There are contexts where it’s easy to get lost, and parentheses can help clarify. But basic Boolean logic shouldn’t be one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is: what should happen once must be before the loop, what should happen every time must be inside the loop.

So you should transform `baseChoice1` to `baseChoice4` before the loop, and `baseChoice` inside the loop. And remember the rules of boolean algebra: not (A or B) is (not A) **and** (not B). BTW, if you want to do some extra action after the decision to continue the loop, and infinite loop with a break can be a handy option.

With all that the code could become:

```
...
cout << baseChoice4 << endl;
cout << endl;

transform(baseChoice1.begin(), baseChoice1.end(), baseChoice1.begin(), ::toupper);
transform(baseChoice2.begin(), baseChoice2.end(), baseChoice2.begin(), ::toupper);
transform(baseChoice3.begin(), baseChoice3.end(), baseChoice3.begin(), ::toupper);
transform(baseChoice4.begin(), baseChoice4.end(), baseChoice4.begin(), ::toupper);

cout << endl;
cout << endl;

baseChoise = "";
for(;;)      
    {
    cout << "Choice: ";

    getline(cin,baseChoice);
    transform(baseChoice.begin(), baseChoice.end(), baseChoice.begin(), ::toupper);


    if ((baseChoice != baseChoice1) && (baseChoice != baseChoice2) && (baseChoice != baseChoice3) && (baseChoice != baseChoice4))
        {
        cout << "This is not a base option, try again!!" << endl;
        }
    else {
        break;
        }
    }
...
```